# Are questions related to science fiction acceptable?

Tags: discussion, scope

I want to ask a question about a phenomenon from a science fiction movie I saw recently. I looked for existing questions related to science fiction and found a wide range of feedback. For example, here are three questions I found and their current status:

- [Does Quantum Physics really suggests (sic) this universe as a computer simulation ? (sic)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/759/246): -2 votes.
- [Could teleportation ever really happen?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1203/246): 4 votes.
- [Time-travel and random events](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2460/246): 0 votes, closed.

Therefore, I must ask:

- Are questions based on science fiction off-topic? The question that got 4 votes was actually considered off-topic in the [Theoretical Physics Q&A Area 51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/23848/theoretical-physics/23955#23955).
- If asking about science fiction is not a problem, then what are the characteristics of an acceptable question and those of an unacceptable question?

Comment: For posterity, there is a [sci-fi Stack Exchange site](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions) where questions that are outside the realm of actual physics might be appropriate.

Comment: Related: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/863/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would say that questions related to the purported physics in speculative fiction are fine as long as they stick to *physics*. That is, it is OK to find your motivation in SF and even to reference a well known book, but not every plot element from a book that you find in the Sci. Fi. aisle is fair game.

In particular, anything that is based on a presumed breakthough (i.e. not found in current science) is going to be a bit shaky.

Also, I feel that you *must* describe the physics situation in enough detail that a reader need not go to the book to figure out what is being asked. That last bit is the biggest failing of ["Orbital mechanics of Dragon's Egg"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1816/520) as I see it.

You can see from your examples that the consensus is not really tight just now. I am not a big fan of high speculative questions: there is no way to judge the correctness of answers (well, there may be ways to judge some really *incorrect*, but...) aside from simple popularity.

---

**side note**: The [theoretical physics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/23848/theoretical-physics) proposal is different from [this site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1908/physics).