# May I ask questions I come across while attempting to write science fiction?

Tags: discussion, scope

Is it allowed to use the site to see if your ideas are plausible? The questions I have [<sup>(1)</sup>](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/79690/) [<sup>(2)</sup>](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/79709/) don't contain any hypothetical technologies or physics, only hypothetical planets, but since I am trying to figure out if a specific scenario is possible according to physics they end up reading a bit like homework questions.

I know how to do math, but I don't know much Physics. When asking these questions I am hoping people can explain the relationship between the variables related to the phenomena and perhaps suggest the variables that have an effect that I hadn't considered.

The thing that concerns me is that I am looking for the answer of a question that I don't quite now how to ask, other than to be very specific. However I also think that were the relationships explained adequately it wouldn't be very difficult for me to reword the question in more general terms that someone else might search for and would have also satisfied me had it been in the search results.

Frankly I've been trying to read more about homework policy than science fiction policy because when I give all the specifics, to a layman like myself, it looks as if it came straight out of a text book, though someone more versed in the subject might immediately spot some naive assumptions.

Either way I am posting these questions knowing that they will be likely altered at least to make more sense if not also to be generalized. But the system has no way of verifying of my intent, and it might look like I am asking someone else to do my work for me. So I am curious as to how much tolerance there is for very specific problems in the context of research for science fiction.

So far though it looks like at the level of specificity in my examples they are fine, as no one has complained or downvoted either of them.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/286/2451 and http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/1025/2451

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate of 1025, since (at least in this particular case) it's about real physics in fictional scenarios, rather than fictional physics.

Comment: Qmechanic: I read those two questions before I posted this one. They were helpful but not what I was looking for. Nathaniel seems to have grasped what I am getting at. But I'll expand a little bit.

Answer (score 10):

I'm sticking with the core idea in [my answer](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/287/520) to [*"Are questions related to science fiction acceptable?"*](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/286/520): the fact that your motivation concerns writing is immaterial to the topicality of a question. As long as it is on-topic, it is on-topic.

That said, I don't like the atmosphere question very much. Far too much going on about your plans and not enough focus on the *physics question*. The question about getting between co-plantets(?) is better.

To sum up my answer is: **stick to the physics**.